# How to ensure correct value from add-on formula on a GoogleSheet published as CSV

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, powerbi, export-to-csv

By creating a GoogleSheet which use formula from an add-on (muFund),
if I publish on the web the CSV and import it as a source on my power bi report,
often (only few times it is working fine) the whole columns calculated by using `muFund` function shows the label `#NAME?` instead of correct value.

**How can I ensure that the value calculated by an "add-on formula" will output a coherent CSV?**

The google sheet is simply this one:
[image]

where as you can see the formula is `=muFunds("nav";A2)`

The published file (csv) is the following:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vS4stYNCZIWp-ScKmCMlR1PHWsxRbsWjykKUhBBpeBcVz9tcDvFewCkgTvUh3QuRTJiRU_w17_H_cma/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv

Probably by downloading the file above, all will go smooth... but probably sometimes it will happen that the calculated values by `muFunds` will be `#NAME?`.... and this is strange. I found also this question not answered:
[Download CSV GoogleSheet with GoogleFinance connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40392693/download-csv-googlesheet-with-googlefinance-connection)

But by using this csv file with a PowerBI Report, the issue happen 9 times on 10 trials. So I wrote following query in Power Query for my report

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document(Web.Contents("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vS4stYNCZIWp-ScKmCMlR1PHWsxRbsWjykKUhBBpeBcVz9tcDvFewCkgTvUh3QuRTJiRU_w17_H_cma/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv"),[Delimiter=",", Columns=3, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"I" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true])
in
    #"I"
```

And here we are with the problem:
[image]

Any suggestion?

Comment: `GOOGLEFINANCE` is a built-in function that has some restrictions that might not be the same of an "add-on formula". Please add a [mcve] including some sample static data , a description of how the custom function is used (i.e. only one formula per spreadsheet , 10 formulas per spreadsheet  or what ever is the intended use).

Comment: thanks for reply, I better write the question. It is the whole column of my table (10 rows only now) and the formula actually is not GOOGLEFINANCE but muFund. I edited also the question

Comment: Hi there @pittuzzo! I understand that this question is about how to ensure that a particular add-on function works. If that is correct, then please share the script of the relevant function so we all can take a look.

Comment: @Jacques-GuzelHeron thanks for reply. I better explain the issue in my question. What do you think? It is so strange... I start thinking it is because the calculation need some times...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be related to the google publish, which probabily is faster than the formula calculation and so the value is not calculated properly.

For this reason I made a small script in order to copy all the values (`Funds`) in another sheet (`FundsValue`) so they can be published in csv without any issue.

In the following the script made:

```
function daily_copy() {
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Funds");
  var destination = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("FundsValue");

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  
  var rangeToCopy = source.getRange(1, 1, destination.getMaxRows(), 3);

//Paste to another sheet from first cell onwards
rangeToCopy.copyTo(destination.getRange(1, 1),{contentsOnly:true});

}
```

In this all values are handled properly so I also add a trigger which daily execute the script automatically